# Using toString() for unit testing in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, tostring

In a unit test, is it generally a good idea to test returned values according to the string their toString() returns?

For example, doing the following to make sure the expected list is returned:

```
 assertEquals(someExpression.toString() ,"[a, b, c]");
```

It seems to me that the considerations are as follows:

**Pros:** Saving time (constructing the actual expected value requires longer code).

**Cons:** The test depends on toString(), which is not formally defined in the doc, and thus can change in any future version.

Comment: It is a good idea to test `toString` if `toString` is part of the API of the CUT. Otherwise it is a bad idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's not part of the tested API. Is it a bad idea to use toString() because it can change in the future?

Comment: If your `toString()` will change in future, you need to change your test too. And that's what another benefit of using unit tests. Clearly, comparing a list with its toString is faulty

Comment: If `toString` is documented to return a particular format then it should be tested. If it just outputs random debugging information, which is often the case, then it should not be tested. But in any case, testing of the object state should be done separately to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only time that I would test on `toString()` of an object is when I have an uneditable class that did not implement `hashcode` or `equals`, but instead implemented a `toString()` to output its field's content. Even then, I won't use a hardcoded string as the equality test, but instead do something like

```
SomeObject b = new SomeObject(expected, values, here);
assertEquals(a.toString(), b.toString());
```

Your approach might save time *initially*, but in the long run it would take far more time just to maintain the test since you are hardcoding the string of the expected result of the `toString()`.

**Edit 1**: Naturally, if you are testing a function / process that outputs a string, that would be one of the times you should be using a hardcoded string as the expected result.

```
String input = "abcde";
String result = removeVowels(input);
assertEquals(result, "bcd");
```

Comment: "hardcoding the expected results" - what do you mean? I'm hardcoding the expected results either way. Do you mean that I'm hardcoding the expected string from toString() which is a bad idea because (mostly) it never has a formal definition?

Comment: Well, tests are all about hardcoding the expected result from a process anyway. But yes, I meant hardcoding the strings. Sorry about that. 

Generally speaking, hardcoding the expected string from toString() is a bad idea because you are basing it from the expected result of the current implementation, which could (and will) change after some time. 

It could also be prone to error, as test creators might as well put the correct expected string just because it is the expected string. It is much more reliable to test the toString() method of an object via toString() of another object.

Comment: Ok, I cannot edit my previous comment. By "...might as well put the correct expected string just because it is the expected string." I meant that there is no basis where the hardcoded string comes from, other than because it is the expected result. If the toString suddenly change, you'd have to ALSO change the test, whereas using the object's toString() on the assert would have no problem with maintaining the integrity of the test. Now that I think about it, it's not really a matter of toString() being documented or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `Assert.assertThat()` method has matchers specific to collections and much more.

For instance, `contains()` works for collections:

```
List<String> someExpression = asList("a", "b", "c");
assertThat(someExpression.toString(), contains("a", "b", "c"));
```

The advantages are:

- You don't need to implement `.toString()`;
- when the test fails, the error message is pretty descriptive, it will say *"Expected collection containig 'b' and didn't find it."*

Try:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.contains;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

List<String> someExpression = asList("a", "c");
assertThat(someExpression.toString(), contains("a", "b", "c"));
```

Comment: Thanks, the list was just an example. Is it generally reasonable to use toString() instead of constructing an object when it saves you lots of code?

Comment: You could use it, if it saves you *that* much of time. But it is a fragile approach (the `.toString()` itself may have a bug and generate false positives!). In general, though, I'd face that need/difficulty as a possible sign of some other design problem. Why aren't the current APIs enough? Why do you need to check so much info, isn't that too much implementation detail? And so on. Nothing is written in stone, so you could use it, but I wouldn't advise it for every case or newbies -- you have to really understand that it is a suboptimal approach (with pitfalls) before you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I use `toString` in particular cases, especially when the equivalent code would be much more complex. As you get more complex data structures you want a quick way to test the entire structure.  If you write code to test, field by field, there is a chance you will forget to add a field.

For my example here
https://vanilla-java.github.io/2016/03/23/Microservices-in-the-Chronicle-world-Part-1.html

```
TopOfBookPrice tobp = new TopOfBookPrice("Symbol", 123456789000L, 1.2345, 1_000_000, 1.235, 2_000_000);
assertEquals("!TopOfBookPrice {\n" +
        "  symbol: Symbol,\n" +
        "  timestamp: 123456789000,\n" +
        "  buyPrice: 1.2345,\n" +
        "  buyQuantity: 1000000.0,\n" +
        "  sellPrice: 1.235,\n" +
        "  sellQuantity: 2000000.0\n" +
        "}\n", tobp.toString());
```

This test fails, why? You can easily see in your IDE as it produces

[image: Display Comparison]

As you get more complex examples, checking every (nested) value and correcting it later when it breaks is really tedious.  A longer example is

```
assertEquals("--- !!meta-data #binary\n" +
        "header: !SCQStore {\n" +
        "  wireType: !WireType BINARY,\n" +
        "  writePosition: 0,\n" +
        "  roll: !SCQSRoll {\n" +
        "    length: !int 86400000,\n" +
        "    format: yyyyMMdd,\n" +
        "    epoch: 0\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  indexing: !SCQSIndexing {\n" +
        "    indexCount: !short 16384,\n" +
        "    indexSpacing: 16,\n" +
        "    index2Index: 0,\n" +
        "    lastIndex: 0\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  lastAcknowledgedIndexReplicated: -1,\n" +
        "  recovery: !TimedStoreRecovery {\n" +
        "    timeStamp: 0\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "# position: 344, header: 0\n" +
        "--- !!data #binary\n" +
        "msg: Hello world\n" +
        "# position: 365, header: 1\n" +
        "--- !!data #binary\n" +
        "msg: Also hello world\n", Wires.fromSizePrefixedBlobs(mappedBytes.readPosition(0)));
```

I have much longer examples where I do this.  I don't need to write a line for every value I check and if the format changes, even a little I know about it.  I don't want the format to change unexpectedly.

Note: I always put the expected value first.

Answer (score 1):

> Using toString() for unit testing in Java

If in your unit test, your intention is to assert that all fields of the object are equals, the `toString()` method of your object under test must so returned a string displaying key-values for all fields.
But as you has underlined, in the time, the fields of the class can change and so your `toString()` method may not reflect actual fields and the`toString()` method was not design for it.

> The test depends on toString(), which is not formally defined in the doc, and thus can change in any future version.

There are alternatives to `toString()` that allows to write nice code without
constraining you to maintain a `toString()` method with all key-value fields returned  or mixing `toString()` initial intention for debugging purpose with assertion purposes.
Besides, unit tests should document the behavior of the tested method.
A code as the following is not self explanatory on the expected behavior :

```
 assertEquals(someExpression.toString() ,"[a, b, c]");
```

1) Reflection library

The idea is mixing **Java reflection mechanisms** with **JUnit assertion mechanisms ( or any Test Unit API you use)**.
With the reflection, you can compare if each field from two objects of same type are equals. The idea is the following : you build a error textual message indicating fields where the equality is not respected between two fields and for which reasons. 
When all the fields were compared by reflection, if the error message is not null, you use the Unit Test mechanism to throw a failure exception with a relevant error message you built previously.
Otherwise, the assertion is a success.
I use it regularly on my project when it turn out be relevant.
You can do it yourself or you can use API like Unitils which can do the job for you.

```
User user1 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
User user2 = new User(1, "John", "Doe");
ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(user1, user2);
```

Personally, I created my own library to do the job with the possibility to add multiple customizations in the assertion.
It's not very hard to do and you can inspire from Unitils.

2) Unit test matcher library

I think that it is a better alternative.
You could use Harmcrest or AssertJ.
It is more verbose that pure reflection but it has also great advantages :

- it documents specifically the behavior expected by the tested method.
- it provides fluent methods to assert
- it provides multiple assertion features to reduce boiler plate code in unit tests

With AssertJ, you could replace this code :

```
 assertEquals(foo.toString() ,"[value1=a, value1=b, value1=c]");
```

where foo is a Foo instance of a class defined as :

```
public class Foo{

  private String value1;
  private String value2;
  private String value3;

  // getters
}
```

by something as :

```
Assertions.assertThat(someExpression)
          .extracting(Foo::getValue1, Foo::getValue2, Foo::getValue3)
          .containsExactly(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override `equals` and `hashCode` (on your own or e.g. using lomboks [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) for that) and do the comparison using them than using `toString`. This way you make the test explicitly about equality and later on you can reuse those methods.

Then you can do (following your example with list):

```
assertEquals(
    someExpression,
    Arrays.asList(new Foo("a"), new Foo("b"), new Foo("c"))
);
```

Comment: But suppose constructing the object requires a lot more code, is it then legitimate to use toString()?  (Even on an instance of a standard java class (like LinkedList) - which its toString() is not documented)